# Messages disappearing after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a view with a list of messages. I would like them not to disappear after I refresh the browser page. I used [this](https://firstclassjs.com/persist-data-using-local-storage-and-angular/) tutorial and created a local storage service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LocalStorageService {
  localStorage: Storage;

  constructor() {
    this.localStorage = window.localStorage;
  }

  get(key: string): any {
    if (this.isLocalStorageSupported) {
      return JSON.parse(this.localStorage.getItem(key)!);
    }

    return null;
  }

  set(key: string, value: any): boolean {
    if (this.isLocalStorageSupported) {
      this.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));

      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  remove(key: string): boolean {
    if (this.isLocalStorageSupported) {
      this.localStorage.removeItem(key);

      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  get isLocalStorageSupported(): boolean {
    return !!this.localStorage
  }
}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-message-receiver',
  templateUrl: './message-receiver.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./message-receiver.component.scss']
})
export class MessageReceiverComponent implements OnInit {

  pluginId: string = '';
  messages$: Observable<Message[] | undefined>;
  gatewayMessagesState$: Observable<GatewaysMessagesRegistry>;
  sub?: Subscription;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private store: Store<fromRoot.State>,
    private location: Location,
    private localStorageService: LocalStorageService
  ) {
    this.gatewayMessagesState$ = store.select(fromRoot.getGatewayMessages);
    this.sub = this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.pluginId = params.get('gatewayId') || '';
    })
    this.messages$ = this.gatewayMessagesState$.pipe(
      map(state => state.gatewaysMessagesMap.get(this.pluginId)?.list)
    );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub?.unsubscribe();
  }

   persist(key: string, value: any) {
     this.localStorageService.set(key, value);
   }

  getCurrentPath() {
    return this.location.path();
  }

  beautify(message: string) {
    return vkbeautify.xml(message);
  }
}
```

```
<div class="templates">
  <a mat-list-item *ngFor="let message of (messages$ | async)?.reverse()">
    <mat-expansion-panel class="panel">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>{{message.date | date:'mediumTime'}}</mat-panel-title>
        <mat-panel-description class="description">
          <div>{{message.title}}</div>
        </mat-panel-description>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <div>
        <pre>{{beautify(message.content)}}</pre>
      </div>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
    <br>
  </a>
</div>
```

The problem is, I have only basic knowledge of Angular and don't really know how to proceed. To be specific, I don't know how to incorporate the persist method into the HTML file. I'm also not sure  if something more is needed.

I've tried using local storage without a separate service as well but didn't manage to succeed either.

Comment: problem is with state, make sure you get the messages from local storage!

Comment: You can try to move the `constructor` code to `ngAfterViewInit` hook, maybe the constructor runs too early.